# Visualizing closed unbounded complex sets

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

In one of my problems in book I had to deal with a closed unbounded complex set and I asked my self what as an example of one, and I couldn't come up with one. To my understanding, a closed set is one for whose points on the closure there doesn't exist discs centered at them of radius $\epsilon>0$ s.t. all discs centred at these points contain points in the given set. On the other hand, an unbounded set is one where there exist infinite sequences which are not bounded. However, I am not too sure with my understanding of an unbounded complex set. If anybody could shine some light on the issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: $\Bbb C{}{{}}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng what I don't understand is if my definition is correct and how to better interpret the sets that are not necessarily the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ but are closed and unbounded.

Comment: Just to add on, is for example, the first quadrant in the Argand diagram closed and unbounded?

Comment: How about the set of complex numbers $z$ with $0 \le \operatorname{Re}(z) \le 1$. Your suggestion also works, if you include the boundaries. Another possibility is just $\Bbb R$!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thank you for the suggestion. All good now, my question has been answered :)

Comment: Of the closed sets worth vizualizing the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) is a pretty food example, IMHO.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, I agree, although the Mandelbrot set famously *is* bounded, so perhaps is not such a good example for this question.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thank you for the suggestion, I will have a look once I get a better grip of analysis and topology as it seems a bit more complicated than what I am after right now.

Comment: Hmmm @IzaakvanDongen I don't see any $\min \operatorname{Re}(z)$ when $\operatorname{Im}(z)=0$, is there any?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, yes, any $x \in \Bbb R$ with $x < -2$ does not belong to the Mandelbrot set. Eg, the iterates for $z = -3$ are $-3, 6, 33, 1086, \dotsc$.